# How to package a command-line tool in Nix?

Tags: nix

Suppose you have a simple collection of `bash` scripts making up a command line tool, with a primary script in `bin/` and some library scripts in `lib/`, all to be packaged with Nix using `tool.nix` with a `default.nix` for convenience:

```
scriptdir
 └─ bin/
     └─ tool
 └─ lib/
 └─ default.nix
 └─ tool.nix
```

**What should `tool.nix` look like in order to correctly package this tool, allowing to execute `tool` in the shell with `tool <args>`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some help from IRC, the following `tool.nix` works:

```
{ stdenv }:

let

    version = "0.0.1";

in stdenv.mkDerivation 
rec 
{

    name = "tool-${version}";

    src = ./.;

    installPhase =
        ''
            mkdir -p $out
            cp -R ./bin $out/bin
            cp -R ./lib $out/lib
        '';

}
```

For completeness, `default.nix` would look like

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.callPackage ./tool.nix {}
```

and can be installed by calling `nix-env -f ./default.nix -i` from `scriptdir`.